# Dynamic Value from Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object like this:

```
obj[0] {Id: 15872, Email: 'abc@hotmail.com'}
obj[1] {Id: 15873, Email: 'def@hotmail.com'}
obj[2] {Id: 16873, Email: 'ghi@hotmail.com'}
```

I want to store this in variable and check if this exist before try to get value to avoid the script get undefined error.

I make an function that will set a default value (---) case the object position does not exist.
But this is a loop, i want to send it to function to sanitize this variable to prevent the script get a error, case it has undefined value

```
let Email;
for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  Email = sanitize(obj, "{$i}Email");
}
 
function sanitize(obj, key, defaultValue="---"){
if(**obj[key]**!=undefined){ 
return obj[key]
}else{
return defaultValue;
}
```

But how can I send the dynamic full variable name (object.array.keyindex) to function so i can check if $obj[$i].$key is defined or undefined
Is it possible?

Comment: What is `Email =  =`

Comment: What's the point of the `Email` variable? You keep overwriting it, but you never use it.

Comment: The argument to `sanitize()` should be `obj[i]`.

Comment: You can just use the null coalescing operator: `Email = obj.Email ?? '---'`

Comment: Is `"{$i}Email"` supposed to be `\`${i}Email\` `?

Comment: @Barmar that's correct

Comment: None of your objects have properties like that. They're all `Email` without a numeric prefix. Why would you want dynamic properties like that?

Comment: @Barmar This is a json return. This return an object array. Thats because it has [i]prefix. I need make this dynamic because i'm not sure all the keys that json return. So i need check first if it exist to avoid get undefined error

Comment: How will you use keys like `1Email`, `2Email`, etc.? Each object will have a different key and you won't know which key goes with each object.

Comment: In fact i should verify like this ..  obj[0].Email === undefined ... obj[1].Email === undefined .. let's supose Email is optional... maybe position 1 can has Email or not.. Thats because i need to check before assign The value

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure what it is your expecting to get back considering you have a loop with a single variable so I made the assumption you want an array returned. If so something like this should work

```js
const objArr = [
  {Id: 15872, Email: 'abc@hotmail.com'},
  {Id: 15873,},
  {Id: 16873, Email: 'ghi@hotmail.com'},
]
 
function sanitize(obj, key, defaultValue="---"){
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    arr.push(obj[i][key] || defaultValue);
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(sanitize(objArr, 'Email'));
```

Comment: The loop is outside The sanitize.. every increment on loop i should check the function to verify if that obj[position].key exist before to try save the value otherwise it can get undefined error

Comment: This does the same thing it just wraps everything into the function. You could do the same thing and remove the function wrapper if you only wanted it run once.